# Multiple errors when building c++ program

Tags: c++, build, compiler-errors

In my program I am building a maze. Whenever I build my project I receive these errors. I know that these errors are referring to lines 1-3 on my header file. But I have put those lines in difference places across my program and I cannot get my project to build. In my header file I am defining a maze class and an coordinate class. I know that my program is not complete yet, but I need to fix these errors so that I can run and test my program.

Header:

```
const int HEIGHT = 1003;
const int WIDTH = 1003;
char grid[WIDTH][HEIGHT];

class Maze
{
    public:
        Maze();
        ~Maze();
        void drawMaze();
        void addPaths();
        void startGame();
        void movePlayer(int);
        bool solved();
        int getKey();
        void addDestinationToGrid();
    private:

};

class Coordinate
{
    public:
        int row, column;
};

Coordinate player;

const static char PLAYER = 'P';
const static char DESTINATION = 'X';
const static char START = 'S';
const static char PATH = ' ';
const static char WALL = (char) 219;
```

Implementation:

```
#include "maze.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include <stack>
using namespace std;


Maze::Maze()
{

}

Maze::~Maze()
{

}

void Maze::drawMaze()
{
    for (int x = 0; x < HEIGHT; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < WIDTH; y++)
        {
            grid[x][y] = WALL;
        }
    }
}

void Maze::startGame()
{
    int input;
    do
    {
            input = getKey();
            movePlayer(input);
    } while (!solved());
}

bool Maze::solved()
{
    return true;
}

void Maze::movePlayer(int)
{

}

int Maze::getKey()
{
    int result = 0;
    while (!solved() && result == 0)
    {
        short MAX_SHORT = 0x7FFF; //111111111111111
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LEFT) & MAX_SHORT)
        {
            result = VK_LEFT;
        }
        else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP) & MAX_SHORT)
        {
            result = VK_UP;
        }
        else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RIGHT) & MAX_SHORT)
        {
            result = VK_RIGHT;
        }
        else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN) & MAX_SHORT)
        {
            result = VK_DOWN;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

void Maze::addPaths()
{
    Coordinate currentLocation;
    Coordinate startLocation;
    Coordinate endLocation;
    std::stack<Coordinate> stack;

    currentLocation.row = (((rand() % HEIGHT) / 2) * 2);
    currentLocation.column = (((rand() % WIDTH) / 2) * 2);

    startLocation = currentLocation;
    grid[currentLocation.row][currentLocation.column] = START;
    player = currentLocation;
    do 
    {
        drawMaze();
        bool canMoveUp = !(currentLocation.row == 0 || grid[currentLocation.row - 2][currentLocation.column] != WALL);
        bool canMoveDown = !(currentLocation.row == HEIGHT - 1 || grid[currentLocation.row + 2][currentLocation.column] != WALL);
        bool canMoveLeft = !(currentLocation.column == 0 || grid[currentLocation.row][currentLocation.column - 2] != WALL);
        bool canMoveRight = !(currentLocation.column == WIDTH - 1 || grid[currentLocation.row][currentLocation.column + 2] != WALL);

        if (canMoveUp || canMoveDown || canMoveLeft || canMoveRight)
        {
            stack.push(currentLocation);

            //choose random location to dig
            bool moveFound = false;
            while (!moveFound)
            {
                int direction = rand() % 4;
                if (direction == 0 && canMoveUp)
                {
                    moveFound = true;
                    grid[currentLocation.row - 2][currentLocation.column] = PATH;
                    grid[currentLocation.row - 1][currentLocation.column] = PATH;
                    currentLocation.row -= 2;
                }
                else if (direction == 1 && canMoveDown)
                {
                    moveFound = true;
                    grid[currentLocation.row + 2][currentLocation.column] = PATH;
                    grid[currentLocation.row + 1][currentLocation.column] = PATH;
                    currentLocation.row += 2;
                }
                else if (direction == 2 && canMoveLeft)
                {
                    moveFound = true;
                    grid[currentLocation.row][currentLocation.column - 2] = PATH;
                    grid[currentLocation.row][currentLocation.column - 1] = PATH;
                    currentLocation.column -= 2;
                }
                else if (direction == 3 && canMoveRight)
                {
                    moveFound = true;
                    grid[currentLocation.row][currentLocation.column + 2] = PATH;
                    grid[currentLocation.row][currentLocation.column - 2] = PATH;
                    currentLocation.column += 2;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (!stack.empty())
        {
            currentLocation = stack.top();
            stack.pop();
        }
    } while (!stack.empty());
    addDestinationToGrid();
}

void Maze::addDestinationToGrid()
{

}
```

Errors:

```
maze.obj : error LNK2005: "char (* grid)[1003]" (?grid@@3PAY0DOL@DA) already defined in Main.obj
maze.obj : error LNK2005: "class Coordinate player" (?player@@3VCoordinate@@A) already defined in Main.obj
C:\Users\Matthew\Desktop\Comp 345\MazeOOP\Debug\MazeOOP.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

Comment: Read the error message, then read the *definitions* of `grid` and `player` in the header file. Then think about what happens when you define the same variable in multiple [*translation units*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29).

Comment: Do you know how header files work? What does #include do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is, as the linker error says, one of multiple definition.

If your header file is included by multiple compilation units, then the lines

```
const int HEIGHT = 1003;
const int WIDTH = 1003;
char grid[WIDTH][HEIGHT];
```

will create a definition of `grid` in each one.

What you need to do is declare `grid` but not define it in the header file.

```
const int HEIGHT = 1003;
const int WIDTH = 1003;
extern char grid[WIDTH][HEIGHT];
```

That tells the compiler, every time it sees those declarations, that `grid` is defined somewhere else.

Then in exactly one compilation unit (aka source file), after including the header, add a definition

```
char grid[WIDTH][HEIGHT];
```

The lack of `extern` tells the compiler that this is a definition.   There must be one and only compilation unit in your project which does this.  If there is none, the linker will complain about `grid` being referenced but undefined.  If there is more than one in your project, the multiple definition error will emerge again.

Comment: Thank you for explaining that very well. Your solution worked perfectly. I was also getting the error for my Coordinate player variable so I was able to change that variable as well.

Answer (score 3):

Declare the global variables in the header and define them in the source, like

Header

```
extern char grid[WIDTH][HEIGHT];
```

Source

```
char grid[WIDTH][HEIGHT];
```